# HTML/CSS performance: flexbox vs table for large data tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm writing a table component in React that would potentially have hundreds of lines, and variable cell widths (in fractions) depending on the table.

What would be the best way to implement this in HTML/CSS, flexbox or a traditional table?

Comment: Check this, It's render just displayable data  https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance is the wrong question here. What is the meaning of the content? If the content is meant to be read as a table of data, then you use a table.

If the content is not meant to be read as a table of data, don't use a table.